# Make "selected" value not visible in html select/dropdown list

Tags: html

I was wondering if it is possible to make the current "selected" value not be visible in my html dropdown list.

For example if I have the following:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

then my dropdown list will have the 4 different options with the 2nd option "Saab" being the selected value.

As is, when the user clicks on the dropdown arrow they will see Saab as the selected value at the top and then see all 4 options with Saab being listed again.

Is it possible to make it so that when they click the dropdown list they will only see Saab once (as the selected value) and then  the other 3 options that are not currently selected, instead of showing Saab twice?

Comment: Why must developers insist on breaking the way users have been used to things working for the last 20+ years?

Comment: Not with HTML alone, you want to use something like JavaScript, or with a server language like PHP.  It can automatically turn off based upon what value is stored in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it with this CSS styles:

```css
option:checked {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

However, user experience may become confusing, so think twice if you really need this behavior.

[:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo class is supported in IE9+.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I am using php to add the selected value (from a DB) at then end of the HTML so it was coming up twice in the drop down list.  (I know there has to be a better way to do it but it's what I have for now)  With the code you provided it will still look normal to the user instead of seeing the Duplicate value.

Comment: oh yeah and that jsfiddle thing is cool as hell! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Ok you could do this using jQuery

```
<select id="dropDown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


$("#dropDown").on("change",function(){
    $(this).find("option").show();
    $("option:selected", $(this)).hide();
});
```

And here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdH4F/)